# With Python 3.6, why can't I write like this?

Tags: python

```
def fun():
    i = 1
    def foo():
        i = i + 1
        return i
```

The second 'i' in line 4 is unresolved, please tellme why?
Thanks!

Comment: you need to initialise i in function foo or declare variable i as global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let python know that `i` is not a local variable of `foo`.  By default, if you set a variable within a function (as you are doing here with `i = i + 1`), then it is assumed to be a local.

So add `nonlocal i` to declare `i` as being outside this scope, and in its closure instead.

```
def fun():
    i = 1
    def foo():
        nonlocal i
        i = i + 1
        return i

    # presumably you want to return foo as well ...
    return foo
```

Now, lets test it:

```
>>> z = fun()
>>> z()
2
>>> z()
3
```